# Sensor that can detect the amount of smoke

Tags: circuit-design, sensor, smoke-sensor

Hello I'm an EE intern in a factory my given task is to desing a circuit where I can measure the difference in the amount of smoke between the filter inlet and outlet. I need a sensor to make it. I considered mq4 could be an option but since its a big filter and chimney im not sure if mq4 would work properly in this scope. Can you help me please.

Comment: Le me see. If your filter is 100 times bigger than mq4, you can make an array of 100 mq4'4 and add the outputs together.

Comment: What kind of "gaz" do you want "sense"?

Comment: Please provide more information about the kind of particles in the smoke.

Comment: Actually my manager told me a circuit that can tell the flow rate at the outlet would be enough. They will contain various chemicals inside of a fridge and this fridge has a chimney with a filter on it. But in time this filter will be worn off and wont work properly ergo there will be less air flow at the outlet. At this point I want my circuit to inform the user with a led turning red from green. How can i measure the flow velocity of the clean air coming out of the filter.

Comment: If you realize your original question wasn't right, edit it to reflect your new requirements.  Some more detail would also be good.  Do you need to know velocity or only if the filter is clogged?  If the latter, a pressure sensor before the filter might be a simple way to check for cogs.

Comment: Flow rate is easy.   Every car made in the last 20-30 years has such a sensor.  It's called a "mass air flow"  sensor i.e.  https://www.autozone.com/engine-management/mass-air-flow-sensor    Pretty simple devices, just google them you'll get tons of info how to implement.   Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The sensor you chose will not work for this.

> High sensitivity to CH4，Natural gas.
>
> - Small sensitivity to alcohol, smoke.

You want just the opposite sensitivity.

Normally Laser particle counters are used with maintenance on cleaning the sampler and shear pressure lines. If this is a coal industry, there may be other methods such as IR reflectance.

Comment: Actually my manager told me a circuit that can tell the flow rate at the outlet would be enough. They will contain various chemicals inside of a fridge and this fridge has a chimney with a filter on it. But in time this filter will be worn off and wont work properly ergo there will be less air flow at the outlet. At this point I want my circuit to inform the user with a led turning red from green. How can i measure the flow velocity of the clean air coming out of the filter.